# sqlite insufficient parameters is supplied to the command when inserting variables

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to get sqlite to update or replace stuff in my table with conditions. The variables `extimermode`, `exhour` and `exminute` are supplied by another `timer.cs`. I get the following error:

> "unknown error. insufficient parameters is supplied to the command".

```
 SQLiteCommand dbcommand = new SQLiteCommand(dbconn);
 dbconn.Open();
 dbcommand.CommandText = " replace into blank (timer0, timer1, timer2, timer3) " + "values (@timer0, @timer1, @timer2, @timer3)";
 dbcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 if (extimermode==0)
 {
     dbcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@timer0", (exhour + ":" + exminute)));
 }
 else if (extimermode == 1)
 {
     dbcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@timer1", (exhour + ":" + exminute)));
 }
 else if (extimermode == 2)
 {
     dbcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@timer2", (exhour + ":" + exminute)));
 }
 else if (extimermode == 3)
 {
     dbcommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@timer3", (exhour + ":" + exminute)));
 }
 else
 {

 }
 dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 dbconn.Close();
```

Comment: You can't have a command text with 4 required parameters and the add only one to the parameters collection (extimermode could have only one value)

Comment: thank you. i got it to work by opening and closing a connection for each if statement and using update.